# How to deploy Django run with Docker compose to Cloud linux server cpanel use set app python?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I tried to deploy Django admin use Docker and Postgres Database to my cpanel use set app python but the project not run, can any body help with the process of how cam make this deployment?

Also I could not able to install the Django site-packages use pip instal in venv.